# Cannot access unique value vector renderer for image in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have had to upgrade to ArcGIS 10.3, I tried to open a .tif image, but in the properties of the image I can not find the unique values option instead I found vector render?!! (look the picture attached). Can any one explain to me what is this for, and how can I find the unique values to my image to add legend to it and start processing.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this is specific to your upgrade in 10.3. Unique value display for raster images is only available for single band (with an associated table, so it must be integer). You can double click on your raster layer when you want to add it and then select a single band. Then, if it is integer type, you'll be able to display it with unique values (make sure that you build a raster attribute table).

Comment: thank you, but i tried that but it also did not help!

Comment: could you try to export your band of interest to a single band and add details about what is not working

Comment: but i need to work it as stack, but i also tried the one single band uploading, still the unique values render is not there!